# Adding GeoServer WFS layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I can't seem to add a WFS layer like [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html). It works when i copy all this code locally but as soon as i change the values to point to my own layer within my own GeoServer

this is the response viewed in firebug:

> Could not locate
>   {http://www.mydomain.com/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=catalog:dataSAR}dataSAR
>   in catalog

This is the relevant part of my javascript:

```
    var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "http://www.mydomain.com/geoserver/wfs",
            featurePrefix:"catalog",
            featureType: "dataSAR",
            featureNS: "http://www.mydomain.com/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=catalog:dataSAR",
            geometryName: "bounds"

        }),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            strokeWidth: 3,
            strokeColor: "#333333"
        })
    })

    map.addLayers([basemap, wfs]);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
```

And this is what my DescribeFeature (featureNS) looks like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:catalog="catalog" xmlns:cite="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite" xmlns:cstars="cstars" xmlns:demo="demo" xmlns:geointcomp="geointcomp" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:gn="http://geonetwork-opensource.org" xmlns:osm="osm" xmlns:test="test" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="catalog">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://www.mydomain.com:80/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd" /> 
- <xsd:complexType name="dataSARType">
- <xsd:complexContent>
- <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
- <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="type" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="altId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="arcId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="startDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="endDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="boundsText" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="acqLocation" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="bounds" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="arcLocation" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="procLocation" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="procVersion" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="procLevel" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="dataFormat" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="sensingMode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="beamCount" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="beamId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="beamMnemonic" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="polarisationMode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="polarisationChannels" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="antennaLookDirection" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="flightDir" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="orbitNum" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="incidenceAngleVariable" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="minimumIncidenceAngle" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" /> 
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="maximumIncidenceAngle" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="dataSAR" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="catalog:dataSARType" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the actual URI/URL for your workspace. From your DescribeFeature Schema it looks like "catalog" which is weird. The other option is to go to the workspace menu in the UI and look there

[image]