# OpenLayers and TinyOWS WFS won't load - 'InvalidParameterValue'

Tags: wfs, mapserver, openlayers-2, tinyows

I've got a TinyOWS on localhost that works fine (both through browser GetFeature and QGIS). But my OpenLayers code fails. I've checked here:
[Display a WFS layer with OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/display-a-wfs-layer-with-openlayers) and here : [How to add a simple WFS layer from GeoServer to OpenLayers map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/how-to-add-a-simple-wfs-layer-from-geoserver-to-openlayers-map)
and other similar questions to no avail. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
    wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows",
        featurePrefix: "tows",
        featureNS :  "http://www.tinyows.org/",
        featureType: "trad",
        geometryName: "wkb_geometry",
        schema: "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&Typename=tows:trad"
    })
}); 

map.addLayers([gphy, wfs]);
```

Here is the xml according to Firebug:

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Here is the post response according to firebug:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ows:ExceptionReport
  xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/ows'
  xmlns:ows='http://www.opengis.net/ows'
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd'
  version='1.1.0' language='en'>
<ows:Exception exceptionCode='InvalidParameterValue' locator='request'>
<ows:ExceptionText>XML request isn't valid</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Here is the TinyOWS config file:

```
<tinyows online_resource="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows"
     schema_dir="/usr/local/tinyows/schema/">
<pg host="127.0.0.1" user="postgres" password="****" dbname="****" port="5432"/>
<metadata name="TinyOWS Server"
       title="TinyOWS Server - Demo Service" />
<layer retrievable="1"
    writable="1"
    ns_prefix="tows"
    ns_uri="http://www.tinyows.org/"
    name="trad"
    title="Träd" />
</tinyows>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your TinyOWS config you write `online_resource="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows"` but in OpenLayers you use another host name - `http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows`. This mismatch causes an error.

Comment: tried that - made no difference.

Comment: Try to move `schema` option from WFS protocol config.

Comment: Ok, can you clarify - are you talking about the tinyows config file or the javascript?

Comment: OpenLayers javascript

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you mean REMOVE or change the schema? If change, what to?

Comment: Simple remove this option.

Comment: Nope, no difference, the xml resonse is still saying exceptionCode='InvalidParameterValue' locator='request'

Comment: In this case try to debug your system using `log` and `log_level` options of [TinyOWS](http://mapserver.org/tinyows/configfile.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help drnextgis - here's the important part of the logfile: [Mon Mar 11 17:00:25 2013] [ERROR] local list type: A type, derived by list or union, must have the simple ur-type definition as base type, not '{http://www.opengis.net/gml}doubleOrNullList'.

[Mon Mar 11 17:00:25 2013] [ERROR] local list type: A type, derived by list or union, must have the simple ur-type definition as base type, not '{http://www.opengis.net/gml}NameOrNullList'.

[Mon Mar 11 17:00:25 2013] [ERROR] XML request isn't valid

Comment: Looks like it might be a  LibXML2 problem? (I've got 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 12.04) http://mapserver.org/tinyows/libxmlschemagmlbug.html

Answer (score 0):

Oops - turns out I had the wrong schema_dir in tinyows.xml. I changed 
    `/usr/local/tinyows/schema/`
to `/usr/share/tinyows/schema` and now it's loading fine. Maybe someone could update the config file example on http://mapserver.org/tinyows/configfile.html ?