# How to host and launch new html files under Geoserver installation

Tags: geoserver

I have gone through many posts to understand how to host and launch new HTML files under a Geoserver installation like this: [Geoserver static file path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20532/15093)
I have saved a test.html file under \GeoServer 2.7.0\data_dir\www\
And when I tried to access that file from http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/test.html  ,
I get:

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> NOT_FOUND RequestURI=/geoserver/web/test.html
>
> Powered by Jetty://

How to resolve this? Did I save the file in the wrong location? Should I do something else to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should be:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/test.html

Make also sure that your data directory is really \GeoServer 2.7.0\data_dir

See for more info:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/staticfiles.html

Comment: Yes, It has worked. I have been trying lot of things to get it. Appreciate your help.