# GeoServer - serving HTML files

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs

Encountering a GeoServer / OpenLayers WFS layer not visible issue, I found [this interesting answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20562/wfs-layer-not-showing). Solution about HTML page on the server surprised me very much as I tried previously to load an HTML page from the Jetty GeoServer without any success, encountering always an error:

HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND RequestURI=/web/ws3.html

Of course, I tried several other places on my `http://localhost:8080/geoserver`.

Can someone confirm that its possible to load any HTML page from GeoServer, and if a special configuration is required to reach this status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can serve html files in GeoServer by placing them in the **www** subdirectory in your GeoServer's data directory.

```
data_directory/
   global.xml
   logging.xml
   wms.xml
   wfs.xml
   wcs.xml
   data/
   demo/
   geosearch/
   gwc/
   layergroups/
   palettes/
   plugIns/
   security/
   styles/
   templates/
   user_projections/
   workspaces
   www/
```

You can then access access those files (ws3.html in this example) by going to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/ws3.html

Comment: Thank you so much ;-) I was getting nuts, I tried under webapps without success.

Comment: So it's working now then? :)

Comment: Yes ! You helped me save quite a long time, I was on the way to give up !