# how can we save vector files in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I'm using **Postgis + tomcat + geoserver + openlayers** for my application.

With the help of some tutorials, I have reached upto getting feature information of layers.

Next I want to edit and save the editable layers permanently.

I got the below code from the internet:

```
 var editable_layer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
   strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
   projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4030"),
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
      version: "1.1.0",
  srsName: "EPSG:4030",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows",
  featureNS :  "http://www.tinyows.org/",
  featureType: "frida",
  geometryName: "the_geom",
  schema: "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/tinyows?service=wfs&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typename=tows:frida"
  })
});
```

After that I have modified the code like this:

```
var editable_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
styleMap: mystyle,
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4030"),
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
srsName: "EPSG:4030",
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
featureNS :  "http://localhost:8080",
featureType: "Test:ramcheck", **/*layer name*/**
geometryName: "the_geom",
schema: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=Test:ramcheck" **/*i don't know how to modify this area*/**
})
});
```

This code is not working.

I can't see the layer contents on the map.

**please help me with a sample code.**

Thanks.

---

### Edit

I got some featureNS, feature type and featurePrefix also.

then I changed my code shown below

```
// create three vector layers
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy],
styleMap: sm,
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4030"),
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    srsName: "EPSG:4030",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
    featurePrefix: "Test", **/*workspace name*/**
    featureType: "Test:ramcheck", **/*geoserver layer name*/**
    featureNS :  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test", **/*Workspace Namespace URI*/**
    geometryName: "the_geom"
})
});
```

But, this error is now shown when I try to save the edits in my layer:

```
 "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces".
```

In openlayers.js below line

```
return data;},createElementNS:function(uri,name){var element;if(this.xmldom){if(typeof uri=="string"){element=this.xmldom.createNode(1,name,uri);}else{element=this.xmldom.createNode(1,name,"");}}else{element=document.createElementNS(uri,name);}
```

My geoserver workspace namespace URI is: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test". Is there any problem in this name?

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: have you seen http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/how-to-add-a-simple-wfs-layer-from-geoserver-to-openlayers-map and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/display-a-wfs-layer-with-openlayers and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20562/wfs-layer-not-showing

Comment: I merged your two accounts, Ramesh: this should make it possible for you to edit your own question.  As long as you do not get any replies, it's fine to keep updating and improving the question, but please don't post modifications or comments as replies.